# Applying custom styles to lightweight-chart

Tags: javascript, typescript, lightweight-charts

[image]

ref: https://info.uniswap.org/#/

So I am trying to figure out how to make the `createChart(...).addAreaSeries` have a smooth line? And bring the labels from x-axis closer to the margin. I am look into [Uniswap source code](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v3-info/blob/master/src/components/LineChart/index.tsx), however there is no hints.

Answer (score 0):

`lightweight-charts` [doesn't support smoothing lines yet](https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues/506) (and probably won't).

As I can see from the picture and the page your referred there is no `lightweight-charts`, it is some other library (which uses SVG instead of canvas). Probably they use `lightweight-charts` somewhere else.